# Shallow routing not working as expected in nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js, nextjs-dynamic-routing

I am trying to change the query params using router.push without reloading the page. I tried using shallow routing as suggested by nextjs docs but it is not working as expected. It should be noted that I am using dynamic routing. So my url looks like this

```
http://localhost:3000/category/865/940/940?parentId=940
```

and as it is dynamic, the slug url would look like this

```
http://localhost:3000/category/[category]/[subCategory]/[productCat]?parentId=940
```

Now when I try shallow routing, it adds the query param but my url becomes something like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/category/[category]/[subCategory]/[productCat]?parentId=940&price=333
```

It should be like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/category/865/940/940?parentId=940&price=333
```

I used shallow in accordance to nextjs docs such as:
`router.push("&price=sdds", undefined, { shallow: true,})`

but it giving me a weird url and refreshes the page.

Answer (score 0):

The usage of `router.push` seems incorrect to me. From the [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#routerpush), the syntax is :-

`router.push(url, as, options)`.

But you are using it as `router.push("&price=sdds", undefined, { shallow: true,})` and not passing the `url`.

You can try the below syntax to just add the new query param to your existing url (The first parameter to `router.push` can be an object as well according to the docs) :-

```js
const newQuery = {
  ...router.query,
  price: newPrice,
};

router.push(
  {
    pathname: router.pathname,
    query: newQuery,
  },
  undefined,
  { shallow: true }
);
```

Comment: I have already tried that but it is still causing the component to render.

Comment: I think this is a issue NextJS 13 is working to resolve. I didn't see you state what version you're using but assuming latest.